# 502 bad gateway error from Separate database and application server

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, nginx, server

My team is building a site connecting to a remote database at another server in China, different from where the site is built. Because of it, when we try to call the remote database, there is a 502 Bad Gateway nginx error.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: some background information, we are building the site in CodeIgniter in PHP, and we use Mysql database

Edit: [image: bad gateway error]

Comment: Is the error printed by CodeIgniter or what? more details are needed please.

Comment: It is not produce by CodeIgniter. I think it is produced by the browser. It looks like a general 404 Not found error, but instead it is a 502 bad gateway error

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: It is added. It is added.

Comment: that's a nginx error, that only says something went wrong. Usually its a Apache + Nginx + PHP problem, but it could be any kind of problem. How are you connecting to the remote database? that's not that easy, usually you need to open ports in firewalls, give users access, etc.

Answer (score 0):

check port and httpd network is enabled

to enable any port use 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables-save

You must allow httpd network

find : 
getsebool -a | grep httpd 
check for httpd_can_network_connect is On if it is not On
Use the below command to turn on : it will resolve your error
command: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Answer (score 0):

So after I research a bit I find out if you call the setsession or retrieve the session function too many times it will issue a bad gateway error 502.

And then I add this to the config file:

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';  // name of the mysql table
```

add add a table to the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
  session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
  user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  user_data text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
  KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

I am using CodeIgniter 2 by the way.

and BAM! It works!